# How to get the position of a hidden object

Tags: jquery

So I have a megamenu that I'm working on, and I want to have it conform to the screen size. When the submenu is dropped down, I don't want it off the edge of the screen. The hiccup in my plan is that I don't know how to detect an element's position before it is actually visible to the browser. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm just dumb. I'm just going to test the parent's position instead. Thanks for the help, though!

Comment: The parent's position does not necessarily need to have the same position. I would not rely on that information. Especially when relative or absolute positioning is involved.

Comment: The child is a fixed width (300px). I'm testing to see if the element could fit on the screen, and if it can't, then I'm moving the starting position of the div. This is what I came up with (see above).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if($(this).offset().left - 90 < window.screenLeft) { 
    $(this).next().css('left','0')
}
else if($(this).offset().left + $(this).outerWidth() + 90 > window.innerWidth) {
    $(this).next().css('right', '0')
}
else { 
    $(this).next().css('left', '-90px')
}
```

Answer (score 3):

An element doesn't *have* a position until it's visible to the browser.

Answer (score 2):

You could give the element an opacity of 0.01, then check its position. This makes is *visible* but still invisible to the normal user.

```
var offset = $(selector).show().css('opacity',0.01).offset();
$(selector).css('opacity',1).hide();
```

Comment: Interesting... I wonder if that would work with zero opacity, too.

Comment: @egasimus Not reliably across browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You could show the element to get its position and hide it afterwards:

```
var element = $('#element');
element.show();
var position = element.position();
element.hide();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/H6d3q/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var offset = $(selector).fadeTo(1, .01).offset();
$(selector).hide();
```